# How to use mercurial or git subrepositories that are connected to the latest release tag?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-submodules, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to use subrepositories that are getting not the HEAD and instead a specific `RELEASE` tag, or if possible the latest tag.

Is this possible, how should I implement this? Did anyone implemented this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about **git**, but **Mercurial** sub-repositories don't link to the head of the sub-repository but to a specific revision.

To set the revision of a sub-repository, you update it to the revision that you want (in your case a specific tag) and then commit the main repository.  That then links the main repository to the specific revision of the sub-repository.

A good guide on Mercurial sub-repositories can be found [here](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/) and the Mercurial sub-repository documentation is [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository).